# Constructor Injection of an ObjectContext using Unity/Prism/MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4, unity-container

I develop an application using WPF with MVVM pattern and Prism. The views are added to the ModuleCatalog and the viewmodels are registered to a unity container. For that I'm using a Bootstrapper which is responsible creating the shell, configuring the unity container and the module catalog.
The question is now, how injecting my EntityContext to the several viewmodels.
First the Bootstrapper:

```
 
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            Shell shell = Container.Resolve();
            shell.Show();
            return shell;
        }
```

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<EntityContext >("Context");
        Container.RegisterType<PersonViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<EntityContext >("Context")));
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
    {
        ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(PersonModule));
        return catalog;
    }
```

The viewmodel looks like that (excerpt)

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private Person _person;
        private PersonRepository _repository;
        readonly EntityContext _context;
```

```
    public PersonViewModel(EntityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _person = new Person();
        _repository = new PersonRepository(context);
    }
```

The module:

```
    public class PersonModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
```

```
    public PersonModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("PersonData", typeof(PersonView));
    }

}
```

The view code-behind:

```
    public partial class PersonView : UserControl
    {
        private PersonViewModel _vm;
```

```
    public PersonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Dependency]
    public PersonViewModel VM
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DataContext as PersonViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _vm = value;
            this.DataContext = _vm;
        }
    }      
}
```

I'm not sure if my approach is working in principle but for the sake of saving changes to the database I need my context in knowledge of changes made to it. Right now it is obviously not working bacause an **ModuleInitializeException** occurs. Stacktrace:
An exception occurred while initializing module 'PersonModule'.
    - The exception message was: An exception has occurred while trying to add a view to region 'PersonData'.
    - The most likely causing exception was was: 'System.InvalidOperationException: The type EntityContext has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
   bei   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`1.FindLongestConstructor(Type typeToConstruct)

   bei   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`1.SelectConstructor(IBuilderContext context)
   bei   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)'.
    But also check the InnerExceptions for more detail or call .GetRootException().
    - The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem.

If there are other solutions for that problem I'm open-minded to it, but I want to use the basic structure presented more or less.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code for your PersonModule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure the container to disambiguate the construction of EntityContext:

```
Container.RegisterType<EntityContext >("Context", new InjectionConstructor(...))
```

Comment: I tried it, but the constructors should be disambiguate, because the auto-generated designer file contains a class EntityContext which inherits from ObjectContext. There three constructors with zero and one parameter - EntityContext(), EntityContext(string connectionString) , EntityContext(EntityConnection connection). Hence it should also work with just Container.RegisterType<EntityContext >("Context"), shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because the container tries to use to constructor with the maximum number of the parameters. If you have two constructors with 1 parameter, it can't figure out how to build it. You have to disambiguate (either configuring the container as in my answer or with InjectionConstructor attribute)